# How to search/replace text with brunch using a regex?

Tags: brunch

Is there any way to search/replace arbitrary text with brunch using a regex? The keyword-brunch plugin exists but it only works if you are replacing a keyword enclosed as {!keyword!}. With Grunt there exists plugins such as grunt-sed. Does anything like this exist for brunch?

Comment: I don't think there exists an analog for sed. But it's fairly simple to write it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It would be pretty straightforward to write an optimizer or `onCompile` plugin to do this, but there are other approaches too that you might find more appealing.

For instance, you mentioned grunt-sed, which is backed by the [replace](https://github.com/harthur/replace) npm package and happens to have a CLI. So you could install that package into your project and set an [npm script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) to run the command you want.

In your package.json

```json
"scripts": {
  "replace": "replace 'foo' 'bar' public -r"
}
```

and then trigger it to run at the end of every Brunch compile cycle using the [after-brunch](https://github.com/Creative-Licence-Digital/after-brunch) plugin

```coffee
plugins:
  afterBrunch: [
    'npm run replace'
  ]
```